# jsonIgnore annotation is not working with Data annotation in lombok

Tags: java, json, date, jackson, lombok

I am trying to ignore some fields to be a part of REST template call.
I am using lombok @Data and trying @JsonIgnore but I see JsonIgnored field in the request body.

code sample:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
class PSRequest{

//other variables

@JsonIgnore
java.util.Date dt;


}
```

I searched and tried below solutions but no luck. Please guide me further using java 8.

> @Getter(onMethod = @__(@JsonIgnore))

> @Getter(onMethod_ = @JsonIgnore)

> @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)

> @JsonIgnoreProperties({"dt"}) at class level

Comment: Not able to reproduce, could you try construct a `PSRequest` and run something like `System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(psRequest));`

Comment: Can you add jackson-version & all configurations that you're using?

Comment: we are using lombok 1.18 and jackson 2.13 with spring boot 2.7

Comment: e = (org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException) org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: No HttpMessageConverter for com.abc.PSRequest and content type "application/json"

Comment: I debug and found above comment error I am getting while doing restTemplate.exchange